# Invariant subspace of linear mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, invariant-subspace

Let $T$ be a linear transformation on a complex vector space $V$ of dimension $4$ and let $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ be distinct eigenvalues of $T$.

Eigenvectors are: $\lambda_1\rightarrow \{v_1,v_2\}$, $\lambda_2\rightarrow \{v_3\}$, and $\lambda_3\rightarrow \{v_4\}$.

I want to find how many invariant subspaces I have.

I know that $V(\lambda_2)$ , $V(\lambda_3)$ , $V(\lambda_2)+V(\lambda_3)$ are distinct invariant subspaces.

Whats about the $V(\lambda_1)$ how many invariant subspaces I have?

If $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$, then $\langle v_1 + \alpha v_2\rangle$ is invariant subspace?

Comment: $V_1=\{v\in\operatorname{dom}T:Tv=x_1v\}$ is invariant

Comment: Yes , but whats about $\alpha\in\mathbb(C)$ $V_1 + \alpha*V_2$ ?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with this "$C$" notation

Comment: I meant complex numbers

Comment: First list all invariant subspaces of dimension 1, then dimension 2, and so on.

Comment: So i have infinite invariant subspaces of dimension 1 beause for every $\alpha$ i have an eigenvector ?

Comment: I don't really understand you, but indeed there are an infinite number of one-dimensional invariant subspaces: $L(v_3)$, $L(v_4)$, $L(v_2)$, $L(v_1+\alpha v_2)$, $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$. $L(v_1,\ldots,v_k)$ is a linear envelope of vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:
The one-dimensional invariant subspaces: $L(v_3)$, $L(v_4)$, $L(v_2)$, $L(v_1+\alpha v_2)$, $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$.

The two-dimensional invariant subspaces: $V(\lambda_1)$, $L(w,v_3)$, $L(w,v_4)$, $L(v_3,v_4)$, $w\in V(\lambda_1)$, $w\neq0$.

The three-dimensional invariant subspaces: $L(v_1,v_2,v_3)$, $L(v_1,v_2,v_4)$, $L(w,v_3,v_4)$, $w\in V(\lambda_1)$, $w\neq0$.

$L(w_1,\ldots,w_k)$ is a linear envelope of vectors $w_1,\ldots,w_k$, i.e. the subspace spanned by $w_1,\ldots,w_k$.